# .getSheets() function return the wrong sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a simple Spreadsheet that only contains 2 sheets. I'm trying to select a cell in the second sheet depending on the coordinates of the active cell in the first sheet.

But I am facing a weird issue. Here is my code :

```
function Arrondis() {
  var firstSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0];
  var cellRange = firstSheet.getCurrentCell();
  var selectedColumn = cellRange.getColumn();
  var selectedRow = cellRange.getRow();
  
  var secondSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[1];
  var secondColumn = selectedColumn-1;
  var secondRow = selectedRow-26;

  Logger.log("FEUILLE 1 : "+firstSheet.getName());
  Logger.log("FEUILLE 2 : "+secondSheet.getName());
  Logger.log("ROW :"+selectedRow+" / COLUMN :"+selectedColumn+" / VALUE :"+cellRange.getValue());
  Logger.log("ROW :"+secondRow+"  COLUMN :"+secondColumn);
}
```

The 2 first Logger functions are perfectly working and both returns two different names. But the next Logger function is not working. It returns the coordinates of the current cell in the active sheet. I want it to always look up in my FIRST sheet no matter where I'm calling it from. I could add a line to set the active sheet at the beginning of my code but that seems too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution:

Since you are working with `active` cells I think the only way to get the `active` cell of an `inactive` sheet is to make the `inactive` sheet `active`.

```
function Arrondis() {
  
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const firstSheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  ss.setActiveSheet(firstSheet);
  var cellRange = ss.getCurrentCell();
  
  var selectedColumn = cellRange.getColumn();
  var selectedRow = cellRange.getRow();
  
  var secondSheet = ss.getSheets()[1];
  var secondColumn = selectedColumn-1;
  var secondRow = selectedRow-26;

  Logger.log("FEUILLE 1 : "+firstSheet.getName());
  Logger.log("FEUILLE 2 : "+secondSheet.getName());
  Logger.log("ROW :"+selectedRow+" / COLUMN :"+selectedColumn+" / VALUE :"+cellRange.getValue());
  Logger.log("ROW :"+secondRow+"  COLUMN :"+secondColumn);
}
```

Comment: That is not working. When you trigger the setActiveSheet function it's also setting A1 as the active cell

Comment: `I want it to always look up in my FIRST sheet no matter where I'm calling it from`. This is what the script does. In order to get the active cell in the first sheet you need to activate the first sheet. Please note, the selected cell will be the cell you see as selected in the first sheet. In your case you have selected A1 and this is why you get A1. @Yuniru

Comment: I tried using .getSheetByName("NAME") instead of .getSheets()[i] and it's not working either. I mean, what is the point of having a function to select a sheet by name if it's actually always looking into the active sheet ?

Comment: @Yuniru that is a valid point. Don't know why they did that. Did you try my solution ? You can get the sheet by its name and then set it as active, then the selected cell in this cell only will be returned. That is the only way you can do that. Alternatively, specify a static range. For example `firstSheet.getRange("B2")`.

Comment: Your solution works exept that setActiveSheet reload the page and the active cells at the same time. I found a workaround by simply changing how I'll work with my spreadsheet to make sure that my script will only be executed from the right sheet.